# I am trying to understand a specific function pointer and assignment

Tags: c, function-pointers

I am reading the source code of the video game “Rise of the Triad: Dark War”, and I came across [a line of code](https://github.com/videogamepreservation/rott/blob/master/rott/_RT_STR.H#L40) I don't understand.

```
void (*USL_MeasureString)(char *, int *, int *, font_t *) = (void (*)(char *, int *, int *, font_t *))VW_MeasurePropString, (*USL_DrawString)(char *) = VWB_DrawPropString;
```

As far as I understand it `void (*USL_MeasureString)(char *, int *, int *, font_t *)` means `*USL_MeasureString` is a function pointer that takes `char *, int *, int *, font_t *` as parameters and returns nothing because of `void`.

But then, I am confused about the rest of the code.

What does it means exactly?

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break this long line into three parts:

```c
void
  (*USL_MeasureString)(char *, int *, int *, font_t *) = (void (*)(char *, int *, int *, font_t *))VW_MeasurePropString,
  (*USL_DrawString)(char *) = VWB_DrawPropString;
```

I believe it's easier to understand now. As you've correctly figured out, `USL_MeasureString` is defined as a function pointer, and the RHS (Right-Hand Side) of the assignment is a type cast applied to the word `VW_MeasurePropString`.

The second part appears tricky on its own, but once you get to know how the following line works, you'll know it's the same:

```c
char (*a) = (char *)"123", (*b) = "xyz";
```

Here, both `a` and `b` are pointers to `char`, so you can think of `char` as a "base type" for the whole line of variable definitions. And of course you can rewrite it as:

```c
char (*a) = (char *)"123";
char (*b) = "xyz";
```

So the part after the comma in your original code can be rewritten as (where `void` is the "base type"):

```c
void (*USL_DrawString)(char *) = VWB_DrawPropString;
```

As you can see, it's just the definition of another function pointer with a different argument list and no type casting.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. This is what I was looking for!